# Ssh relay without opening ports

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have machines `A` and `B` that can access a `Relay` machine via ssh, but not vice versa. Can I access machine `B` from `A` via the `Relay` machine without opening ports except `22` as that port is the only one accessible?

For example, a possible solution would be to `ssh` from `B` into `Relay` and opening files for reading `stdin` and writing `stdout`. Connecting from `A` to `relay` allows reading and writing into these files for communication to `B`.

Is there a way with command line tools to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is obviously already a port open on the relay, otherwise ssh wouldn't be possible.

The only way I see is for B to ssh to the relay and along with that, open a reverse tunnel which A can then use.  You're looking for the "-R" option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

1. ssh A to relay and forward a local port (for e.g. `ssh -L 6022:127.0.0.1:6022`)
   This command forwards local port 6022 on A to port 6022 on relay over SSH.
2. ssh B to relay and forward a remote port to local ( `ssh -R 6022:127.0.0.1:22`)
   This command forwards remote port 6022 on relay to local port 22 on B
3. Now on A, connect to localhost port 6022 using ssh and should be able to login to B.